# Javascript - join arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

I have method in a class that returns 8 arrays with 8 objects each:
`[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}] [{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}] etc.`
the result I would like to get is one array containing all these objects, like this:
`[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]` etc.
what function should I use to get this?
I tried with concat() but here I have to pass another array as a parameter...

Comment: `.flat()` seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
`arr.flat(depth);`

This example is given in the [mozilla javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
arr1.flat();
// [1, 2, 3, 4]

var arr2 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr2.flat();
// [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]

var arr3 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr3.flat(2);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be that [.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to merge all the objects into a single array, one way to do this would be to use `Array.reduce`.

```js
const result = [
  [{}],
  [{}],
  [{}],
  [{}],
  [{}],
  [{}],
  [{}],
  [{}]
];

const final = result.reduce( (acc, curr) => {
  return [...acc, ...curr];
}, []);

console.log(final);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the below as your array of objects structure

```js
let array = [[{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}], [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}], [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}]]

let out1 = [].concat.apply([], array)

console.log(out1)
```

If you use latest ES then you could try with this [array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), as mentioned by sirko in the comments

```js
let array = [[{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}], [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}], [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}]]

let out2 = array.flat()

console.log(out2)
```